Bluetooth stopped working out of the blue on Ubuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 about two weeks ago and everything was working fine - including Bluetooth - and then it suddenly stopped working: the Bluetooth button simply disappeared from the top right corner menu in the panel.
I restarted multiple times - it didn't help.
The output of systemctl status bluetooth:
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Aug 05 22:19:52 Jacks-HP-Ubuntu systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).

How do I fix this?

It turns out that this wasn't Ubuntu's fault nor Linux's fault - it was the hardware's fault: there are people reporting this issue elsewhere on both Windows and Linux and people who are dual-booting report that, when they experience this problem on one OS, the other is always affected as well.
The (presumably temporary) fix is obscenely simple: shut down the computer, unplug its power cable from the wall (or, if it's a laptop, open it and remove the battery), wait a couple of minutes, plug it back in, turn it back on, and that's it.
Source: https://forum.level1techs.com/t/aorus-master-x570-ubuntu-bluetooth/152747/5
Where I found the source: https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/unable-to-start-bluetooth-service/37439
